# TDA- Persistence Diagram and Barcodes using image data (and TDA R package)

Tags: general-topology, image-processing, topological-data-analysis

I am very very new to Topological Data Analysis (TDA) and I am trying to apply the method described in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.09158.pdf). I understood everything but stuck on methodology section (3.2) where he described:

> use R package "TDA" [FKLM14] to compute the 0- and 1-dimentional superlevel set pesistent homology barcodes of the surface...

where TDA package link is [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TDA/TDA.pdf).

Now what I am confused is, because most of PH or TDA is done on "clouds of data points" such as a circle etc, idk how that would be translated into an image which is a 2D matrix (with each entry being a pixel). When we use clouds of data, those data are only given in (x,y) coordinates, not with intensities (or we can think as z coordinate)...

So the question is... how do we convert these intensities into simplexes?

Comment: Cubical complexes are very natural for dealing with Image data. Maybe this link will be useful: http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1019117/FULLTEXT01.pdf